# BASH Store output of command with variable into another variable

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to store the output of the following command into a new variable without any luck so far:

```
lineNumber="$(perl -ne '{$n=$. if /$inpuTtext/} END {print '$n\n'}')"
```

where $inpuTtext is from the previous line which reads the user's input.

```
read inputText
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `grep -n "$inputText" file.txt`?

Comment: With `perl -ne '{$n=$. if /$inpuTtext/} END {print '$n\n'}')` I want to search for the last occurence of the text entered by the user and return it's line number to store it in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

single quoted strings can be concatenated with double quoted to allow to expand inputText

```
lineNumber="$(perl -ne '{$n=$. if /'"$inputText"'/} END {print "$n\n"}')"
```

also single quotes around `$n\n` were closing the perl command (not nested).

note that inputText is injected as is into perl command so for example if inputText can contain a `/` it must be escaped because used as separator.

otherwise inputText can be passed with environment :

```
lineNumber="$(inputText=$inputText perl -ne '{$n=$. if /$ENV{inputText}/} END {print "$n\n"}')"
```

Comment: Throws error `Number found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/20/09"
        (Missing operator before 09?)
Illegal octal digit '9' at -e line 1, at end of line
syntax error at -e line 1, near "/20/09"
Illegal octal digit '8' at -e line 1, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
`

Comment: this why i wrote  " if inputText can contain a / it must be escaped  "

Comment: so if I want to search for date, lets say 20/09/08 I should type 20\/09\/08?

Comment: yes otherwise your perl command will be invalid or don't generate code as in last example

Comment: It still throws error even if I escape the date like in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Here I am redirecting the standard error to standard output and I have removed the `""` as well:-

```
lineNumber=$(perl -ne '{$n=$. if /$inpuTtext/} END {print '$n\n'}') 2>&1
```